# Unitarity of quantum evolution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-computer, unitarity

In [this](https://www.pdx.edu/nanogroup/sites/www.pdx.edu.nanogroup/files/(1995)%20Charles%20Bennett%20-%20Quantum%20Information%20and%20Computation.pdf) paper by Charles Bennett, he says on page 25,

[image]

I understand why U(XOR) gives the result it does but why is that a consequence of its unitary property? Thanks

Comment: Looks to me to be less a consequence of *unitarity* and more of *linearity*.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not sure what you mean by linearity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quantum operations are [unitary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix). That means they correspond to a [change of basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis). Furthermore, the vectors making up the basis you're switching to (or from) must be mutually perpendicular and have unit length (i.e. we're always dealing with [orthonormal basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis)).

If $U_{xor} (a|0\rangle+b|1\rangle)$ wasn't equal to $a(U_{xor} |0\rangle) + b (U_{xor}|1\rangle)$, then $U_{xor}$ couldn't correspond to a change of basis. $U_{xor}$ would be applying non-linear twists and stretches to its input, instead of just rotating and reflecting it in various ways. That's how $U_{xor}$'s unitarity tells us that $U_{xor} |\nearrow,x\rangle$ must equal $\sqrt\frac 1 2U_{xor} |\updownarrow,x\rangle + \sqrt\frac 1 2U_{xor} |\leftrightarrow,x\rangle$. Because $|\nearrow,x\rangle = \sqrt\frac 1 2|\updownarrow,x\rangle + \sqrt\frac 1 2|\leftrightarrow,x\rangle$ and $U_{xor}$ is linear.

If all of that sounds weird to you, it might be because you haven't studied [linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra) yet. Understanding linear algebra is an important precursor to understanding quantum mechanics or quantum computation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I understand the linear algebra but I am not sure what you meant by $U_{xor} |\nearrow\rangle$ As far as I understand $U_{xor}$ is the two qbit CNOT gate so what does it mean applying it to a single qbit?

Comment: @ANANDAPADHMANABHANS That was a typo.

Comment: Still, the property that $U_{xor} |\nearrow,x\rangle = \sqrt\frac 1 2U_{xor} |\updownarrow,x\rangle + \sqrt\frac 1 2U_{xor} |\leftrightarrow,x\rangle$ is a property of linearity of the operator as far as I can see. I am unsure how it is a consequence of unitarity

Comment: @ANANDAPADHMANABHANS Unitarity implies linearity. It's part of the definition.